# Update attribute in model with many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 models that have a many-to-many association(an Event has many Products and Products have many events), and I am trying to add one product to an event. I have used single table inheritance to implement the many types of products that the system needs to handle, this is why in the error below `Lighting` is the model name not products.
I have the following method in my controller to add the product to the event, however the following error occurs:

```
NoMethodError in AddeventController#add

undefined method `each' for #<Lighting:0x007fd4bc798c70>

app/controllers/addevent_controller.rb:5:in `add'
```

And my action looks like:

```
  def add
      @event = current_event
      product = Product.find(params[:id])
      if @event.update_attribute(:products, product) #This is line 5
        format.html {redirect_to @event, notice: "Product added to event"}
      end
    end
```

Current_event is just a method that pulls the id of the event from the session.

So whats going wrong?

Comment: each for Lighting, but I see no Lighting. That's probably where your problem is coming from.

Comment: You should post the code where this .each is being called -- can't diagnose something we can't see

Comment: @Trip see my edit about that.

Comment: @Rabbott I don't know where .each is being called as i've not done that.

Comment: post your addevent_controller.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to wrap the product in an array, as many to many relations work on arrays.

```
@event.update_attribute(:products, [product])
```

Also, the name of the action suggests that you want to add the product in the event and not just replace the event's products with the single product. so may be you should do:

```
@event.products << product
```

Comment: Thanks and also thanks for spotting the future error of replacing all the products not just adding one.